# Normalization on relational schema with no functional dependencies

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

`R = ( A, B, C, D )` - No functional dependencies are valid in the relational schema R

For the above relational, what is the highest normal form? I have a question where i am supposed to identify the highest normal form and decompose it into BCNF if it is not in BCNF.

Comment: There are always FDs--at last the trivial ones. Also you have the definition of BCNF so apply it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no valid FDs holds (a part from the trivial dependencies), then the only candidate key is ABCD, and the relation is both in 3NF and BCNF.